# Mismatched input 'block of statements' error in tradingview pinescript

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I am trying to test a strategy on tradingview through pine script. I need RSI data from 5 candles back and i am using this code to do that, where i am trying to use a for loop to get this data.

```
//for loop test
`enter code here`RSIBonus = 0
for i = 5 to 1 by 1
    if RSI [abs(i)] > 35
RSIBonus := RSIBonus + abs(i)`enter code here`
```

But every time i get this error that  `block of statements end expecting 'block of statements'`. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same error

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to Python, Pine Script expects the code within your `if` and `for` blocks to be indented. Try indenting the last line:

```
for i = 5 to 1 by 1
    if RSI [abs(i)] > 35
        RSIBonus := RSIBonus + abs(i)
```

Because there are no block scope curly braces as eg. in Javascript, pine script wouldn't have any idea what code belongs into the the condition/loop and where the main programm continues, otherwise.

See the [documentation](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Expressions_declarations_and_statements.html#id10) for examples.